# Is PCP recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines

I want to know whether Post Correspondence Problem(PCP) is recognizable. I learnt how to demonstrate the undecidability of PCP. I thought to use the similar approach for recognizability too i.e. to considering MPCP and show whether it is recognizable. I am not sure if it is a good approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pure CS theory and therefore should probably be migrated to cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: should the "turing-machines" tagged be eliminated from this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Post Correspondence Problem is indeed recognizable. Here are four ways to see this:

1. **Build a recognizer for it.** Given a set of tiles, you could imagine a TM that lists off all sequences of exactly one domino, then exactly two dominoes, then exactly three dominoes, then exactly four dominoes, etc., progressively increasing the number of dominoes each time. If the TM ever finds a series of dominoes where the tops and bottoms match, then it can accept. Otherwise, it will loop infinitely.
2. **Build a nondeterministic TM for it.** Design a nondeterministic TM that, given a set of tiles, nondeterministically guesses a series of tiles to line up, then checks whether the tops and bottoms match. If so, it accepts; otherwise it rejects. This NTM will then accept any "yes" instance since it can always guess a valid series of dominoes, and will not accept any "no" instances because it can never guess a valid ordering of the dominoes.
3. **Build an enumerator for it.** Run a breadth-first search over the infinite trie of all strings of tiles. For each string of tiles, if the top string matches the bottom one, output it.
4. **Build a verifier for it.** The inputs are the set of tiles and one possible string of tiles. The verifier checks that all tiles in that string are in the set of tiles and that the strings on the top and bottom rows of the tiles match.